spaCy cannot detect 1 as part of a date
def extract_dates(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    dates = []
    for word in doc.ents:
        if word.label_ == "DATE":
            dates.append(word.text)
    return dates

print(extract_dates("The period starts from 1 June 2019 till 1 September 2022 inclusive"))

This gives me:
['1 June 2019', 'September 2022']

As you can see, the 1 before September is not recognized as part of a date.
